# Dispatch a NSNotification based on a custom core data setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I want to change a `UITableViewCell` based on whether or not a file exists in the documents directory. I feel like this should be Notification Based and the notifications should be sent when the objects `isAvailable` property has changed.

I don't want to create threading problems by accident. Since I am manipulating my core data objects on the main thread, should it be ok to setup a custom setter on my Concrete class to post a notification?

What would be the best way to do this? should I create my own notifications, or should I hook into something that core data already posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple if you use `NSFetchedResultsController`. This class can be used in combination with a `UITableView` to reduce memory overhead and improve response time.

You can find docs at [NSFetchedResultsController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSFetchedResultsController) and [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

In addition, you can implement delegate methods for `NSFetchedResultsController`. Implementing `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods, it allows you to listen for operations like add, remove, move, or update in your data (the `NSManagedObjectContext` you registered for) and, hence, in your table.

A very good tutorial on the subject is [core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller). Here you can find all the elements to set up a `UITableView`, a `NSFetchedResultsController` and its delegate.

Said this, about your question you can use this technique to change the content of a `UITableViewCell` when `isAvailable` property (of a specific `NSManagedObject`) changes. In particular, you should implement the following delegate method to respond to specific changes (see the comment).

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: // <---- here you will change the content of the cell based on isAvailable property
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           break;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, thanks! that is very helpful. I will get started implementing right away!